# Sony VAIO NetworkManager Network Manager wont allow me to select wi-fi network in applet Enable Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi

This worked for me. The solution is specific to Sony Vaio labtops though.

I'm a seasoned user of Linux,(33 years) so when my Wi-Fi suddenly stopped working I was a bit surprised.

The "Enable Wi-Fi" check box in the NetworkManager Applet would not toggle to "ON", meaning I could not check it no matter how much I tried.

I worked through most of the solutions on forums

rfkil - to see if blocked, all good iwconfig - to see if the interface was there, all good

Plus comparing Wi-Fi/Hotspot setups to a working machine, albeit a earlier version of Debian. all good though.

**SOLUTION:** When I sat down on the couch I must of accidentality toggled the WIRELESS switch on the Sony Vaio to OFF!

**( located at the front left hand side edge of the laptop )**

I wish I had known about this before, I was gifted a laptop, I've always been a Desktop guy. I spent hours crawling through posts, so I thought I'd post this. I hope this post saves someone time.

My question would be is I suppose..
Is this bad form to post a solution where a solution is already found?

*I signed up for Linux decades ago, and I'm still not complaining. :)*